# Can users only be allowed to open certain sites when they log in in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

Let's say I have a site collection and 5 subsites (A, B, C, D, E). Is it possible that when certain users log in, they will be directly presented with subsite B.

So far, in my experience, every user when he or she logs in, they will always be presented with a default page. From that page, they choose which subsite they want to open.

Answer (score 0):

You could let users login to the SharePoint site with subsite url.

For example: If user A want to login to subsite A, user A could use subsite url like "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/subsiteA" then user A will be directly presented with subsite A.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that before. Thanks a lot @Casey Yang

Comment: It's my pleasure, you can accept the answer and upvote if it helps.